Slow performance of nginx as reverse proxy
I use nginx as a reverse proxy in the following configuration: Ubuntu 22.04, nginx 1.18.0, access to two web services on host A and host B, which are accessible via https://a.foo.com:8443 and https://b.foo.com:8443 respectively.
Nginx “routes” these to 10.1.1.10:8080 and 10.1.1.20:8080 and provides certificate termination. The configuration file is listed below.
The problem is that the web services have a much slower behavior than when I use direct port routing with DNAT (iptables firewall without nginx): a.foo.com:8443 to 10.1.1.10:8443 and b.foo.com:8444 to 10.1.1.20:8444 :
up to 5 s response time compared to less than 1 s with DNAT.
Nevertheless, I have to use the same port in both cases, which is only possible with a reverse proxy.
Does anyone have an idea how to improve the performance of nginx in this case?
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
}
http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  client_max_body_size 500M;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  gzip on;

  upstream hostA {
    zone upstreams 64K;
    server 10.1.1.10:8080 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=2s;
    keepalive 4;
  }

  upstream hostB {
    … .20:8080 …
  }

  server {
    listen 8443 ssl;
    server_name a.foo.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/..;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/..;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://hostA/;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Request https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header   "Connection" "";
      proxy_connect_timeout   180s;
      proxy_send_timeout      180s;
      proxy_read_timeout      180s;
      send_timeout      180s;
    }
  }

  server { #.. same for hostB
  }
}

